# VueJS JavaScript path finding leads to a default path

Tags: javascript, path, vuejs2

I'm trying to import external js file to vue component and embed that imported file to a script tag.
Here is my code.

```
created(){
  let ckeditor = document.createElement('script');
  ckeditor.setAttribute('src',"./jsmaps/jsmaps.js");
  document.head.appendChild(ckeditor);
}
```

But it gives an error

> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “http://localhost:8080/jsmaps/jsmaps.js”.

**jsmaps folder** is not in the **localhost**.
It is inside the my vue js project folder's src folder.
Why this take **localhost** in default and how I override this default behavior to load that script which is inside my Vue project's **src folder**

Comment: what path do you expect?

Comment: Path inside the project. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by my self.
Basic reason for this error is I gave only

> ('src',"./jsmaps/jsmaps.js");

It takes path correctly after I give the full path.

> ('src',"src/student/jsmaps/jsmaps.js");

I only give the relative path only it leads to **localhost** to find the path. =)